# how to print void in java

Tags: java, void

The below statement returns void

```
Pattern lazy = Pattern.compile("X??");
Matcher lazyMatcher = lazy.matcher("X");
if (lazyMatcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println(lazyMatcher.group());
}
```

Is there way to print void in java.

I tried below 2 statements , but does not help

```
System.out.println((String)lazyMatcher.group());
System.out.println(lazyMatcher.group().toString());
```

=============================================================================
Updating

why am i getting String when i call below

```
System.out.println(lazyMatcher.group().getClass())  // returns string
System.out.println(lazyMatcher.group()) // returns void
```

Comment: `Is there way to print void in java.` ??what do you except to see in console ??  `"void"`  ?

Comment: Which statement returns void?

Comment: lazyMatcher.group() --- returns void

Comment: [`Matcher::group()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29) does not return `void`, it returns `String`.

Comment: thanks... confused inbetween

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the `Void.class` you can use.
If you try `Void.class.toString()` it will return

```
class java.lang.Void
```

Comment: It seems i can also use java.lang.Void.TYPE

Answer (score 14):

void is nothing. You don't print it. If you wan't to print "void" you can do

```
System.out.println("void");
```

Comment: seriously LOL , though perfect ans :) :)

Comment: This is epic. ROFL :)

Answer (score 12):

void is not an object. All the void return type states is that nothing will be returned from the method. So the answer is no, there is no way to print void, as there is nothing to print.

With regards to your edited question, you are getting a String because Matcher.group() returns a string not void. See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Comment: It seems i can create object of type void...                               Object obj = java.lang.Void.TYPE;  
System.out.println(obj.toString());

Comment: If you view the documentation for that (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) it says it is an 'uninstantiable placeholder class to hold a reference to the Class object representing the Java keyword void'. So this isn't saying that void is an object, it is a reference to the class object representing void. So the object you are creating is a Class object, not void.

Comment: That is not true. Check my answer. Java has the Void type just for the case the OP asked about.

Comment: @AdamArold Apologies if I misunderstood it, but i assumed that the return type of TYPE was a class, as the documentation says that the return type is a Class<Void>?

Answer (score 3):

You cant print something that isn't there.